# Hide Search Results Style Resources Readers Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

Currently on SharePoint Enterprise 2016.

I have documents uploaded to a site collection that I don't want visible to everyone. I changed the library settings to remove the library from being searchable. However, it's still visible in search results due to the "Style Resources Readers" group. How can I change/alter this?

Ideally, we'd only want documents populating in search results for only those who have permissions to access them. Is there an easier way to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint search is security trimmed. As long as the users are not present in any group(s) or are not directly assigned permissions to the container and/or items, they will not appear in search results for those users. Are the users present in the Style Resources Readers group? If not, you're all set. If so, you can either remove them or customize the permissions on the library and remove that specific group.

Comment: NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users are in this security group. Isn't this required for users to be able to see master pages and styling?

Comment: If you're using Publishing, right. You should instead remove the group from the library permissions.

Comment: That's what I thought - I just realized that they were a hidden user group in the library permissions. Thanks!